# Passing src for pip to conda env create

Tags: conda

I am creating a conda environment using `conda env create --json --force -f ${CONDA_ENV_FILE}` where there is a `pip` section in the file that contains some `editable` git installs. I would like to control where the git clone happens. [`pip` has a flag `--src`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-src) that can be set to control that. Is there a way to have conda pass that flag to pip?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr sort of: you can use `PIP_SRC=<src_folder>` to override the default `src` folder.

Sadly conda doesn't currently support use of the `--src` flags because it runs `pip install -r requirements.txt` under the hood, without any way of injecting global pip options (see [source code](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/conda_env/installers/pip.py)).
The [requirements.txt file format specification](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format) specifies that `--src` isn't a supported global option, so we can't go down that route, however there is a `--install-option` option that is supported on a per project basis that allows you to pass arbitrary options to the dependency's `setup.py` invocation however at this stage it's too late as the dependency has already been downloaded at this point.

One saving grace is the fact all of [pip's flags can be specified as environment variables](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#environment-variables), so if you want to specify `pip install --src <src_dir> blah` you can use `PIP_SRC=<src_dir> pip install blah`